# Error: Mail command failed: 550 5.7.1 when trying to send e-mail from Firebase Functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-extensions

I've tried to use nodemailer on cloud functions to send e-mails with Firestore's oncreate event. Every time I try to send an email from a cloud function, it throws the following error:

```
Error: Mail command failed: 550 5.7.1
```

It also says that I should check my `MX` and `SPF` records of my domain.

I've tried to use the following SPF records with no success:

```
v=spf1 include:spf.whservidor.com include:_spf.google.com include:_spf.firebasemail.com include:sendgrid.net ~all
```

I've also tried to use the *Trigger Email from Firestore* extension but got the same problem.

Does anyone know what should I include in my SPF records to get this working?

Comment: I doubt you have an MX or SPF TXT record problem that is causing the 550 error. What is the command that failed? Most likely the SMTP server rejected the `RCPT TO` command. Double check the sender email address and that you are connecting to the correct SMTP server.

Comment: Great! I did a misspelling with the sender. Could you please post this as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SMTP 550 error is often caused by specifying an incorrect recipient email address. The SMTP `RCPT TO` command is being rejected.

Double check the email address that you are sending email to.